# Why am I getting a "Call to a member function on a non-object" error?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm working with the Zend framework, backed by MySQL, and trying to set up an index view. However, with the code I have, I keep getting the "call to a member function on a non-object" error and I don't know how to solve it. Here's the Controller for my index page:

```
 public function indexAction() {
     $dImage = new Application_Model_DImage();
 }
```

Here's the code for the DImage model that it references:

```
public function getImageDesCol ($Id) {
    return $this->getDb()->fetchCol("SELECT description FROM d_image WHERE d_id = ?", $Id);
}
```

Finally, here's the source of my Index view page where I'm trying to display the values from the DImage model:

```
  <?php $description = $this->dImage->getImageDesCol($id) ?>
  <label><?php echo $description[0] ?></label>
```

When I load that page, I get the "Call to a member function `getImageDesCol()` on a non-object" error instead of a rendered page. Since I'm new to the Zend framework and PHP in general, I feel like there's something obvious that I'm missing. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the **Application_Model_DImage** object to the view, or else the view does not know of an object with that name. Do this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $dImage = new Application_Model_DImage();
    $this->view->dImage = $dImage;
}
```

Then you will have your $dImage available to your view scripts.

Your view scripts execute in the context of a **Zend_View** object, but you were creating your **Application_Model_DImage** object in the context of your controller (an instance of **Zend_Controller_Action**). As such, you need to explicitly pass to the view whatever objects the view scripts will use. By default, **Zend_Controller_Action** has a *view* object ready for you (check [here](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_Controller_Action.html#Zend_Controller_Action)).

Comment: Yup that works but I am unable to display data which it should suppose to do.

Comment: @Varun The problem probably lies in the getImageDesCol($Id) method. Instead o returning data from the DB, try to return a fixed string (e.g. return "test!";), and check if it prints. If it prints, then debug your DB query.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
 public function indexAction()
 {
     $dImage = new Application_Model_DImage();
 }
```

To:

```
 public function indexAction()
 {
     $this->dImage = new Application_Model_DImage();
 }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I just it did but its not working. I get the same error message